# How can I specify the URL alias when importing nodes into Drupal 7 (with the Feeds module)?

Tags: 7, feeds, uri, path-aliases

I'm importing a site into Drupal 7, using the Feeds module.  I don't see any way to specify the URL alias for each node (which I want to control on most every page).  How can I do this?  (If the Feeds module cannot do it, is there a way to do it in bulk after the import?)

***Update***: in case it's not clear, I want to have a column in my CSV that lists the URL alias that I want for a particular node.  I don't want the URL automatically generated.  I want completely control over the URLs, without having to manually specify them in the Drupal admin UI.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to do this. I found it helpful for auto-aliasing URLs in bulk, and it is customizable... it works pretty well if you use taxonomy to improve work site flow.

Comment: It's unclear to me how that will help, since pathauto is for automatically generating URL aliases so I don't have to, but I want to control this myself and not have it auto-generated.  (Unless there's some hidden feature of pathauto I've missed.)